# Is it possible/advisable to combine unit testing and integration testing?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mysql, integration-tests

I've built a Python script that consists of about 20 functions that extract data from MySQL via `.sql` files (I'm currently trying to learn SQLAlchemy ORM), do something to it and then put it back in MySQL. The process involves changing the same data multiple times so future steps rely on previous steps.

I've built a unittest test case per function that boots up a test database, populates it with data a fixture (in this case an Excel file - I will probably move this to a `.sql` dump file in future) and then tests the output against data also held in a fixture. I'm not sure if these class as unit tests as they test only one function or integration tests as they simulate interaction with other system components. Apparently though it [doesn't matter what you call them.](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/48265/367981)

Currently each test is self-contained and the data used doesn't simulate a full process flow - it uses simplistic inputs that don't relate to previous examples. I now want to test the end to end flow of the process and currently I foresee this as building a single test case with every step of the process (function) in it. I then insert a dataset at the beginning and test the output at the very end. Worth mentioning that I've taken to thinking of the current tests being unit tests and the end to end test being an integration test, hence the title of this post.

My question is this... should I not simply build my **current** fixture data so that it follows a logical pattern from start to finish? That way I get the benefits of discretely testing the outputs of every step whilst ensuring I also have the end to end view too. It seems like a good solution but there's something nagging me that this could be a pain to maintain over the long term.

Any advice for a Python and testing newbie?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do I need unit test if I already have integration test?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/204786/do-i-need-unit-test-if-i-already-have-integration-test)

Comment: I think it's a good thread and one I'd not read before - after reading it there seems to be a case for unit and integration tests both being needed. I guess my question still stands though - how closely do you couple the fixtures used by unit and integration tests?

Comment: I guess I'm hypothesising that if the data is exactly aligned then you get an integration test from a series of unit tests...

Comment: @gnat: This question seems to suggest to _combine_ unit and integration tests, not about having both kinds of separate test suites.

Comment: You need to define "unit" for yourself. It's quite common in python to treat public api or "entry point" as a unit. Main reason for this – implementation details should be easy to refactor. Covering underlying functions in isolation is rather bad practice – if it's not public API, nobody should care about changes. So write tests from top perspective, maximize coverage, add low-level testing, if you need to simulate really rare edge case

Answer (score 46, accepted):

> Is it possible/advisable to combine unit testing and integration testing?

Doing both unit testing and integration testing? Overwhelmingly yes.

Mashing them together in a single test suite? Not advisable.

Based on your comment, it seems you already understand the purpose of both, so I won't repeat that here. But I do want to address your suggestions that they can be combined in a single test sequence.

> I guess I'm hypothesising that if the data is exactly aligned then you get an integration test from a series of unit tests

To achieve this, your unit tests need to store state that another unit test can therefore rely on. This means that your test is no longer a unit test, as it relies on an additional dependency (the state store).

What you're describing here is a series of integration tests, not a series of unit and integration tests.

Also, it's completely normal for a single integration test to assert itself at every step, e.g.:

- Arrange: set up fixture
- Act: create new Foo
- Assert: was the Foo created?
- Act: update Foo with new data
- Assert: was the Foo updated?
- Act: delete the Foo
- Assert: was the Foo deleted?

Those aren't three separate tests, they're a single integration test that is comprised of multiple steps. If you had only asserted everything at the end, then you would've been unable to distinguish cases where the Foo was never created (and the rest of the logic didn't throw exceptions) and ones where the Foo was correctly created and deleted.

When you describe your suggested unit tests that follow each other, that sounds like what you really need is a *combined* integration test that is comprised of all of those steps.

> should I not simply build my current fixture data so that it follows a logical pattern from start to finish? That way I get the benefits of discretely testing the outputs of every step whilst ensuring I also have the end to end view too.

Using the example integration test I mentioned, consider a bug whereby a created Foo can be deleted, but an updated Foo cannot. For some reason (randomly chosen for the purpose of this example), when you update a Foo, it renders the Foo undeleteable.

When you run your suggested test suite:

- "Unit" test `createFoo` => PASS
- "Unit" test `updateFoo` => PASS
- "Unit" test `deleteFoo` => FAIL

Your sequence of "unit" tests (quotes because they're really mini integration tests) would flag the wrong step (i.e. delete) as the problematic one. The create would succeed, the update would succeed, but the delete would not.

Based on that test report alone, you would conclude that something is wrong in the delete logic. If you were a betting man, you'd bet money that the bug was being caused there.

However, if you had created actual unit tests and some multi-step integration tests, you would've narrowed down the issue better:

- Unit test `createFoo` => PASS
- Unit test `updateFoo` => PASS
- Unit test `deleteFoo` => PASS
- Integration test `createAndDeleteFoo` => PASS
- Integration test `createAndUpdateAndDeleteFoo` => **FAIL** (failure reported on the delete step)

Now, you wouldn't conclude that the bug is in the delete logic, since the delete unit test passes. As a betting man, you would *not* be betting money on the delete logic being broken, as the test report almost invariably suggests that it's the updating of a Foo which is causing an issue in the deletion of that same Foo.

This is of course a cherrypicked example, but it highlights the purpose of having separate unit tests and integration tests. If unit tests pass and integration tests fail, that means you have narrowed the problem down to an interaction between two components, rather than a component itself.

These sorts of issues are very hard to spot naturally, as each code block you look at will individually appear correct (since each unit test passes). The cause of the bug is most likely a side effect whose cause (in the update logic) and effect (in the delete logic) are spread over different locations, making it very hard to spot, especially in a sufficiently large codebase.

That's still not an easy bug to fix, but at least now you know that you're looking for a side effect and can put the update/delete logic side by side when hunting down the bug.

---

As a general rule, when people suggest taking a shortcut in writing tests (as you have), the intention is generally good (trying to achieve the same thing with less effort), but in almost all cases it leads to less informative test failure reports, e.g. not being able to pinpoint to the location of a bug.

Your suggested testing strategy still catches the vast majority of bugs that you're going to encounter during development, but some types of failures will become harder to troubleshoot.

I'm not going to tell you you're not allowed to employ your testing strategy. I'm just pointing out the difference between your strategy and the "normal" (very much mind the quotes) testing strategy.

Comment: This is an awesome response - thank you! A big side benefit is that you've demonstrated the importance to me of integration tests not simply running end to end - they should also overlap different portions of the process to isolate issues.

Comment: The only, but key, follow-up I have is that I won't be storing a state with any unit test. Each one will be initiated with a discrete pre-defined input fixture and checked against a discrete pre-defined output fixture. They won't rely on any previous test. What I was trying to get at was that the input fixture for one test will be the output fixture for the previous test - I may even call the same file but there will be no 'between-test' dependency.

Comment: I think in summary I'll build the 'unit' tests with the fixtures in this way but then still build a suite of integration tests over the top. Sound like a plan?

Comment: @Jossy: Glad to see I could help :) As to your second comment, notice that in such a case (where I do agree it's mostly "real" unit tests), you would be wholly unable to spot the "undeleteable updated Foo" bug as you would never chain the two operations together; thereby losing out on the benefit of actual integration tests. As to your third comment, that solves the issue I just pointed out in your second comment :)

Comment: Perfect - you've been a superstar. The key thing around the integration tests I do build is that though they will have the same input as the 'unit' test that comprises the first 'step' I will only be testing the integration test output against the output of the final 'unit' test in the sequence. Doing it this way will help me keep the number of fixtures down...